# 「リキっちまって」What is っちまって suposed to mean here?

Tags: colloquial-language, anime

The sentence: 悪い、拳 当たったよな リキっちまって…

In Oshi No Ko anime there's a scene where a guy punches the MC with force, despite it being supposed to be an act. I know that リキ here refers to the force/power, but where does the ちまって in 「リキっちまって」come from? is it a contraction of 行っちまって?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a form of リキる, contraction of リキってしまって→リキっちまって, but I'm not sure that's a common word even as a slang. I would guess the meaning is the same as [力む](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%80/) - exerting extra/unnecessary force.

(If it was リキむ instead, the same form would be リキんじまって.)

Comment: Thanks, I was confused as I couldn't find リキる in a dictionary, but it's probably a pretty rare slang.

Comment: I can't find it in a dictionary nor with a general web search.